# SSE: cast double** to _m128d**

Tags: c++, sse, sse2

Casting normal double* to a _m128d* is pretty easy and comprehensible.
Suppose you have an array like this:

```
double arr[8] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0};
```

Then the `_m128d` presentation kinda would look like this:

```
_m128d m_arr[8] = { [1.0,2.0] , [3.0,4.0] , [5.0,6.0] , [7.0,8.0] };
```

because always 2 values are stored, if you can say that (that's how I imagine it).
But how will the values be split up if I use a 3x3 matrix instead??? E.g.:

```
double mat[3][3] = { {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0} };
```

I am trying to just sum up all values in a matrix but don't really get how to do this effictively with SSE, therefore I need to understand how the matrix is dealt with `_m128d**`.
Does anybody know?

Comment: 2D arrays ain't double pointers.

Comment: Yes right, quite pedantical. I hope the question is clear anyhow

Comment: Oh, so you knew that. Sorry for having assumed the opposite.

Comment: I would have asked a question on matrices and pointers if I wanted to know that. If you don't want to contribute to the question then leave your offensive attitude for yourself. But i suppose you don't

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive. I honestly assumed you thought 2D arrays are compatible with double pointers. Now I believe to have understood your question and answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that multidimensional arrays are stored in one continuous block of memory (the C standard guarantees this). So you can use a simple pointer to reference them:

```
double mat[3][3] = { {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0} };
double *ptr = (double *)mat;
```

Then you can iterate over the 9 numbers using this pointer and dereference it to obtain a double, which then can be cast/converted to another type.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually quite useful.